# Distribution of transformed poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Let X follows Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda\gt0$ and $Y=aX$, where $a\gt0$ is a constant.

Q. What will be the $PMF$ of $Y$?

Since by using the M.G.F we have
$M_Y(t)=M_X(at)=(e^{\lambda(e^{at}-1)})$.
What next I should do to derive its distribution.

Comment: $Y$ takes the values $ak$ where $k$ is a non-negative integer with probability $e^{-\lambda}\lambda ^k/k!$.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math Stack Exchange! To use $\LaTeX$, you should put the formula between dollar signs.